# f, g are functions on a dense subset D in R

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

For a dense subset D of R, f, g : R → R are functions such that f(q) = g(q) for every q ∈ D. Show the following:

(1) If f is continuous and g is monotone, then f(x) = g(x) for every x ∈ R.

(2) If f and g are both continuous, then f(x) = g(x) for every x ∈ R.

So I proved 2  by assuming for any x in R, since D is dense for R there exists a sequence x that goes to x0. Since f and g are both continuous, f(x) and g(x) go to f(x0) and g(x0). Since f(q)=g(q) f(x)=g(x) and by uniqueness of limits f(x0)=g(x0). I don't know how to prove (1)... any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've lost your "New Contributor" label. Mazel Tov! Now it's time to [learn MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). :-)

Comment: For your proof of $2$, is $x_0$ an element of $D$? Can someone also expound on what he means by the uniqueness of limits at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WLOG we assume that $g$ is non-decreasing. For any $x\in\mathbb R$ we can find $\{x_n\}\subset D$ and $\{y_n\}\subset D$ such that $x_n\uparrow x$ and $y_n\downarrow x$. Hence
$$f(x_n)=g(x_n)\leq g(x)\leq g(y_n) =f(y_n).$$
Letting $n\to\infty$ and using the continuity of $f$ give the desired result.

Comment: So for any delta and epsilon greater than 0, |xn-x| < delta and |f(xn)-f(x)| is less than epsilon... where do I go from there?

Comment: @Alex The continuity of $f$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(y_n)=f(x)$. So $f(x) \leq g(x)\leq f(x)$ hence $f(x)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality we may assume that $g$ is a non decreasing function. Now for $x \in R$ we can an increasing sequence $<x_n>$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and a decreasing sequence $<y_n>$ in $D$ such that $y_n \rightarrow x $. Now from the sequential definition of continuity $f(x_n)=g(x_n)\leq g(x)\leq g(y_n)=f(y_n)$. Now taking the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then, using the continuity of $f$ we have the desired result.

Comment: Since such an answer already given by @Feng Shao, kindly forgive me for the same.